# Best way to test user authentication for APIs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, token

I'm building an API with Ruby on Rails and (attempting to) build user auth with a gem called Devise Token Auth. But I'm uncertain about the best way to validate / authenticate a user before each controller action.

I know of the `before_action :authenitcate_user!` call but it thinks my users aren't signed in since I'm making calls from an external client.

Do I need to pass other arguments along with my requests that I'm not thinking of? Like a token or session id?

Answer (score 1):

try simple_token_authentication https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication works with Devise and is easy to integrate.
You just need to send the user authentication token and email, to perform the authentication.

Comment: How is this different than Devise Token Auth? And how does it solve my issue of authenticating a user before each controller action?

Comment: Hi, if your are building an API, you must send the authentication params for each request to your server, this gem validates the params (email and token by default) on every controller that includes **acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User**, you can also do **acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, only: [:method1, :method2]**

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a lightweight API app I would consider using [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock).

Devise is a great solution for traditional apps where you need a full authentication solution with signups, password editing etc. But it is designed around session based authentication and the codebase is somewhat of a monster due to the crazy amount of customizations available - with token based auth you will only be using about 1% of it.

A basic setup would be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Knock::Authenticable
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_user
end
```

Now if we send a request without a valid `Authorization: Bearer SOME_TOKEN` header Knock will return a `401 - Unauthorized` response.

We can test it like so:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def token
    Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: users(:one).id }).token
  end

  it 'does not allow an unauthenicated request' do
    get users_path
    assert_response :unauthorized
  end

  it 'allow an authenicated request' do
    get users_path, headers: { authorization: "Bearer #{token}" }
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```